# Is there a possibility to inject anything after executing timeout function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, settimeout

For example, we have code like this,

```
    let a = 0;
    setTimeout(()=>{a++},0);
    console.log(a);
```

As I understand everything in timeout callback will be executed after all call stack functions will be executed, and only then timeoutCallback will go to execution stack from 'queue'.

My question: 
  Is there a possibility to inject anything after executing timeout function and get a result from timeout callback? (without waiting when all execution stack will empty)

something like this:

```
    let a = 0;
    setTimeout(()=>{a++},0);
    console.log(a);  // 0
    //some mystery things happened
    console.log(a); // 1
```

Comment: Is it an entirely hypothetical question (which would be too broad), or is there an use case (which would need to be exposed in an [edit] to this question)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't get code back out of the timeout queue once it's been sent there. Instead, move the code into a handler function and send that to the timeout queue. You can then save the setTimeout as a variable, and later you can kill the timeout before it has fired and immediately run the function.

```js
let a = 0
function timeoutHandler() {
  a++
  console.log("Counted to " + a)
}

var timeout = setTimeout(timeoutHandler,10000)

clearTimeout(timeout)
timeoutHandler()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a possibility to inject anything after executing timeout function

Is this a security/immutability question? Because your reference to variable `a` is an example of closures and can be modified from multiple places.

```js
let a = 0;
setTimeout(()=>{a++},0);
console.log(a);  // 0
    
a++              //some mystery things happened (ie Closures)
    
console.log(a);  // 1
```

If your requirement is to keep, `a` from being unintentionally affected from other parts of the code, use immutable identifiers (ie `const`) or pass the incremented value using higher-order functions.